# Map loaded callback in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I want to print page with Openlayers 3 map after start up. If I call `window.print()` after init map, there was empty page because map didn`t rendered yet. So I need a callback after map loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/crazzzy/f6kjdsjz/

Answer (score 2):

You have to register listeners for `tileloadstart`, `tileloadend` and `tileerror` events on all your tile sources. In the `tileloadstart` listener, you increase a counter, which you decrease in `tileloadend` and `tileloaderror`. When the count is `0`, your map is loaded, and you can open your print window.

The [Tile Load Events example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/tile-load-events.html) shows the explained approach in more detail.